# Python help changing the character in this column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So, I have a dataframe (df) and inside I have a column named 'US Stock Market DJI Close'. The responses in the columns are 'positive', 'negative' and 'weekend'. Is there a simple way to change 'positive' to 1, 'negative' to 0 and remove all 'weekend' values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, when you say "remove" all weekend values, do you mean set them to nan or drop the row?

To replace positive and negative, you'd do:

```
df.loc[df["US Stock Market DJI Close"] == "positive"] = 1
df.loc[df["US Stock Market DJI Close"] == "negative"] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, and if I make the variable nan would it effect me in plotting the column?

Comment: Depends. You can avoid the nan's just while plotting or you can remove all values of weekend with: df = df[df["US Stock Market DJI Close"] != "weekend"]